# Use S.DS.ActiveDirectory namespace for enumerating OU properties

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, directoryservices

I want to retrieve all the properties of an organizational unit with something similar to `S.DS.AccountManagement`.

Since `S.DS.Accountmanagement` is only for users and groups, is it possible to use the `S.DS.ActiveDirectory` namespace in this case? I have not found many examples using `S.DS.ActiveDirectory`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string LdapPath = @"LDAP://" + DomainServer.HostName + "." + domainName + "/" + strOuCn;

DirectoryEntry adEntry = new DirectoryEntry();

adEntry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.ServerBind;
adEntry.Path = LdapPath; //loads OU to adEntry
```

then you can check your properties for example :

```
adEntry.Properties["distinguishedName"]
```